# how to make a post call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#testDiv").load("http://localhost:7908/ToLoadAjax.aspx");
});
```

It seems it is a Get http request.

[image]

How to make it a post call please?

Comment: A good read http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post('http://localhost:7908/ToLoadAjax.aspx', function(data) {
        $("#testDiv").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, it becomes post, thanks, will accept the answer after sometime

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data,
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});
```

Btw, read the documentation! https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

But it doesn't make any difference do either a GET or a POST unless you are really sending in any data.

Comment: Lol. Okay. First, Why do you not want to do a GET but a POST instead?

Comment: because I am scraping a website which has a lot of post calls and I want to get the data from those calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.post()` see [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more informations.